# Compatible Plutonomy cabal.project for plutus-apps

Tags: plutus

I want to use Plutonomy , but it only (currently) works with two `Plutus` versions as per https://github.com/well-typed/plutonomy#flags.
How can I get a compatible `cabal.project` -- especially one that also works with `plutus-apps` ?